# asp.net mvc checkbox uncheck on check of toher

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an MVC 2 view with two checkboxes like this:

```
                    <%: Html.Label("Is Customer")%>
                   <% 
                       accountStatus = Model.AccountStatus == "Customer" ? true : false;
                    %>
                    <%: Html.CheckBox("IsCustomer", accountStatus.Value, new { onclick = "uncheckAll(this);" })%>
```

I want that if one checkbox is checked then other one is uncheked. I am getting ids like this:

```
function uncheckAll(ID) {
    var search_form = document.getElementById('frmAccountEdit');
    var IsTrialAccount = document.getElementById('IsTrialAccount');  // getElementsByTagName("input");
    var IsCustomer = document.getElementById('IsCustomer');
```

How to make this worked ?

Comment: Have you considered using radio buttons? Sounds like an ideal candidate for what you are attempting.

Comment: no, The form has other checkboxes as well and i need to make of of them checked only in certain case.

Answer (score 0):

Alright try the below. It will clear both IsTrialAccount and IsCustomer but then check whichever checkbox was checked. If you don't want "IsTrialAccount" to have the same functionality then just don't add it to its button click event and remove the "|| inputs[j].name == "IsCustomer"" part

```
function uncheckAll(Checkbox)
{
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
      if(inputs[j].type == "checkbox" && 
        (inputs[j].name == "IsTrialAccount" || inputs[j].name == "IsCustomer"))
      {
         inputs[j].checked = false;
      }     
    }
   // Check the selected checkbox
   Checkbox.checked = true;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This will uncheck all checkboxes of the form which is what I dont want. I want to toggle between these two checkboxes only.